Deseo obtener la fecha y hora del cliente usando PHP
Estoy desarrollando un script en PHP y necesito capturar la fecha y hora del cliente, sin embargo con la función date_default_timezone_get() capturo la fecha y hora del servidor y yo necesito la del cliente. Así por ejemplo, si el cliente está en Alemania, necesito capturar la fecha y hora exacta de Alemania y no la del servidor que se encuentra en USA.
Sé que se puede hacer con JS, sin embargo mi script es puramente PHP.
Alguna sugerencia, por favor.
Este código uso en PHP, sin embargo me captura la fecha y hora del servidor:
$zona_horaria = date_default_timezone_get();

date_default_timezone_set($zona_horaria);

$fecha = date("Y-m-d");

Encontré este código en JS, sin embargo no puedo usarlo porque mi script es PHP puro:
var resolvedOptions = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions()
console.log('Zona horaria: ', resolvedOptions.timeZone);


No te respondo formalmente porque no estoy 100% seguro, pero que no se puede. La información adicional que envía el cliente al servidor está en las cabeceras y que yo recuerde no hay datos con fechas y horas. En general yo siempre uso UTC-0 el cual es un punto en común tanto para el cliente como para el servidor y de esta manera me olvido de las diferencias horarias

No se puede. PHP, como otros lenguajes backend, no ejecutan nada en el cliente. Esto es así por diseño. Tendras que usar JS para comunicar esa información.

No puedes obtener la fecha/hora del cliente sin el cliente. Debes obtener ese dato en el cliente y si lo necesitas en el servidor se lo puedes pasar desde el cliente usando Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.
